# looking for something similar to caching

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a query that takes about a minute to complete since it deals with a lot of data, but I also want to put the results on a website. The obvious conclusion is to cache it (right?) but the data changes as time goes by and I need a way to automatically remake the cached page maybe every 24 hours.

can someone point me to how to do this?

edit: I want to make a "top 10" type of thing so it's not displaying the page that is the problem but the amount of time it takes for the query to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching the results of the query with a 24hr TTL (expiry) would probably work fine. Use a fragment cache assuming this is a chunk of the page.

You can setup memcached or redis as stated to store the cache. Another thing you can do is setup a job that warms the cache every 24 hrs (or as desired) so that unlucky user doesn't have to generate the cache for you.

If you know when the cache is expired base on a state or change in your database you can expire the cache based on that. A lot of times I use the created at or updated at fields as part of the cache key to assist in this process.

There is some good stuff in the scaling rails screencasts by envy labs and new relic. http://railslab.newrelic.com/scaling-rails, a little out of date but the principles are still the same.

Also, checkout the caching rails guides. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Finally, make sure indexes are setup properly, use thoughtbots post here: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/163627511/a-grand-piano-for-your-violin

Typed on my phone so apologies for typos.

Answer (score 0):

Think a little beyond the query.  If your goal is to allow the user to view a lot of data, then grab that data as they want it rather than fighting with a monsterous query that's going to overwhelm your UI.  The result not only looks better, but is much, much quicker.

My personal trick for this pattern is [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net).  It's a grid that allows you to use Ajaxed queries (which is built in) to get data from your query a "chunk" at a time that the user wants to see.  It can sort, page, filter, limit, and even search with some simple additions to the code.  It even has a plug-in to export results to excel, pdf, etc.

The biggest thing that Datatables has that others don't is a concept called "pipelining" which allows you to get an amount to show (say 20) plus an additional amount forward and/or backwards.  This allows you to still do manageable queries, but not to have to hit the database each time the user hits "next page"

I've got an app dealing with millions of records.  One query of all data would be impossible....it would just take too long.  Grabbing 25 at a time, however, is lightning fast, no tricks required.  Once the datatable was up, I just performance tuned my query, did some indexing where needed, and voila.....great, responsive app.

Here's a simple example:

```
<table id="example"></table>

$('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/processing/file.php"
} );
```

Comment: don't think this is what I need. in my case, new data is added to the table every few minutes and so the averages returned by my queries may give me different numbers every time.

Comment: Auto update/update totals on page is trivial....The point is that you're only getting the data that is required for the UI at the time you're showing it.  If you've got a query that takes minutes, it's either grabbing serious amounts of data, or it's horribly inefficient.  I can do complex joins into tables with millions of records and still have the UI responding in under 5 seconds.

Comment: sorry this is my fault I did not describe my problem well enough. I am working with a top 10 list so it's not that I am displaying lots of data but fetching the top 10 from millions of rows is the problem.

Comment: If you're only grabbing 10 results then you've got a query issue.  Even though you're searching through millions of results, it should be much more responsive without much work.  Do performance testing...check your queries.  Also, ensure that you've properly indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cache store that allows auto-expiration after a certain length of time.

Memcached does it, Redis too I guess !

Comment: Yes, redis certainly does this.